# 3D scatter plots and 3D graph visualization in Java

Tags: java, 3d, charts

I'm looking to create views of scientific data in Java.

The data is a mathematical graph consisting of points in 3D space.

Are there any Java-based frameworks for creating 3D graphs in Java so that I can:
1. Plot points as spheres,
2. Connect some of the spheres with thin cylinders,
3. Draw flat triangles between some sets of three spheres?

Something like a molecule viewer, with the ability to insert 3D polygons.

Web searches seem to bring up either 3D mesh-plotting tools, "3D charts" (for "pretty representations of 2D/1D data); but I can't seem to find anything that is suited to my data.

I guess this could be done in Java 3D, but I'd prefer to use existing code so that I don't have to write code to manage user gestures (for rotation, etc.) and so that I can simply work with simple coordinates, rather than mapping into the transformation and scene-graph perspective of Java 3D.

Comment: Anyone has found any solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Depending on your system you could always run a Python matplotlib program from within Java. I'm not sure how well Jython would work or if that goes in the opposite direction... but I think they already do what you want: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d_demo.html

Comment: [VisAD](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/visad.html "VisAD")

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you try http://github.com/jzy3d, which will really help you to do what you want.
Regards,
Martin

Comment: I just discovered it here ...Personally, I find it great.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have to end up doing a lot of it from scratch (Sorry, I don't know any libraries), you might want to try [Processing](http://processing.org/). It's Java and might have some of the functionality you're looking for to start building a charting tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a good mathematical library that does representation in 3d but you can always export to a plain txt file and use good old gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

We are thinking about integrating [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT) (it's a scientific library C++ from CERN) with our Java app. But integrating C++ app in Java is a [problem in itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534752/how-to-make-c-code-draw-on-java-components).

EDIT: I was also pointed to [JAS3](http://jas.freehep.org/jas3/), that is a scientific java lib that has 3d plots.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related answer of me: I have summary of existing tools and show a alternative option to create interactive charts with Gnuplot in a JPanel

[Java 3D plot library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library/6668950#6668950)