# How to make 3d surfaces in Java?

Tags: java, 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 3D plot library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library)

I develop some Java application, and now I've got a problem: I want to make 3D surface for some data, but I have never used any Java libraries for this task. I've found 2 popular libaries: TeeChart and JMathPlot, but I don't know how I can draw some 3D surfaces using this labs. Please, give me an example or advice. Thank you very much.

UPDATE: I need 3D surface which be available for rotating and has got X,Y,Z lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Java3D for a couple of games and it has been pretty good, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "make 3D surface for some data" so you mean you want to draw a 2D graphic on a 3D object? or do you mean you want to create 3D lettering for your data? If you make your question a bit more specific everyone else and I will be able to better help you. And I know for sure you can rotate things in Java3D and I'm pretty sure any 3D engine or library will allow you to rotate things, if it didn't it would be kind of pointless to draw things in 3D eh?

There are a ton of Java3D tutorials:

- http://www.java3d.org/tutorial.html
- http://www.vrupl.evl.uic.edu/LabAccidents/java3d/

Here is where you can download the documentation for Java3D:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.4.0-doc-oth-JPR

The documentation will tell you essentially everything you could ever want to know about Java3D

Here is where you can download Java3D, select the appropriate operating system of course

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR

Hope this has been helpful, the first 2 tutorials I listed are pretty short and sweet so they'll get you started as quick as possible.

---

Specifically here is a page that rotates a cube, you can see the example code and the images at the bottom.

- http://www.vrupl.evl.uic.edu/LabAccidents/java3d/lesson02/indexb.html

Answer (score 0):

Try **jMonkeyEngine** - seems it's most powerful API for java 3d

Here is example how to give an object's surface a material and texture. 
 How to make objects transparent, or let colors "leak" through partially
  transparent textures. How to make bumpy and shiny surfaces.

http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_material

Comment: I don't need 3D objects, I need to draw 3D graphic (surface). For example, z=x+y. I need to get 3d surface for it.