# Is it possible to draw 3D area chart using jFree?

Tags: charts, jfreechart

Is it possible to Create 3D area chart using jFree ?

[image]

If yes,  can someone point me to the right direction ?
Any workaround possible?

Comment: See this recent [forum update](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18464).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, jfreechart does not support 3d plots.

**(Update from comments):**

I would also suggest looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library), which suggests some alternatives like: jzy3d, JMathTools, Surface Plotter, JavaPlot, etcetera

Comment: If that statement is correct (I do not know), then it is a valid answer IMO. A quick search turned up [this link](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18464) which also suggests it is "not supported".

Comment: also suggest looking at this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library)

Comment: I (JFreeChart author) confirm that JFreeChart does not support 3D area charts.  I've created a new chart library (Orson Charts 3D) that supports 3D area charts amongst others.  It's not free like JFreeChart.